# Is it possible to create network graph using from left to right as tree graph using highcharts?

Tags: angular, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I am trying to generate a networkgraph using highcharts and highcharts-angular. My task is to generate a network graph some thing like a sleeping tree graph as in the picture below. I am trying all the series options as in the [Highcharts api docs](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.networkgraph) . However, I am not able to achieve.

[image: Tree from left to right]

Whatever be the series option I tried, I am seeing the network graph as in  [image: this picture attached].

Is it possible to generate the networkgraph using highcharts as I require? If so, how can I do it? Below is the series data, I am using

```
[['Continents','Asia'],
 ['Continents','Europe'],
 ['Continents','Africa'],
 ['Africa','Congo'],
 ['Africa','Kenya'],
 ['Africa','Zimbabwe'],
 ['Europe','Sweden'],
 ['Sweden','Finland'],
 ['Asia','India'],
 ['Asia','China']]
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Organization chart](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/organization-chart) seems more suitable for your need.

With the option `inverted: false`, the result looks like what you want.

Comment: @Jeffrey Schmitz, I know that we can use organization for similar structure. But I want to know, If I can make networkgraph to be created in simar way. What I just want is, the continents node in the example has to be placed in the left most instead of center.